# Can't compile STK (The Synthesis Toolkit) with node-gyp (C++)

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, linker-errors, node-gyp

I'm trying to make an audio software (a DAW) using Electron to create the window and c++ to play audio / generate audio / apply audio effects.

I have been searching for a simple, powerful, and cross-platform library to play and process audio, and I've found `The Synthesis Toolkit` and I'm really happy with it.

Here is the code (it's from the STK demo programs):

```cpp
#include "BeeThree.h"
#include "RtAudio.h"
using namespace stk;

// The TickData structure holds all the class instances and data that
// are shared by the various processing functions.
struct TickData {
  Instrmnt *instrument;
  StkFloat frequency;
  StkFloat scaler;
  long counter;
  bool done;

  // Default constructor.
  TickData()
    : instrument(0), scaler(1.0), counter(0), done( false ) {}
};

// This tick() function handles sample computation only.  It will be
// called automatically when the system needs a new buffer of audio
// samples.
int tick( void *outputBuffer, void *inputBuffer, unsigned int nBufferFrames,
         double streamTime, RtAudioStreamStatus status, void *userData )
{
  TickData *data = (TickData *) userData;
  register StkFloat *samples = (StkFloat *) outputBuffer;

  for ( unsigned int i=0; i<nBufferFrames; i++ ) {
    *samples++ = data->instrument->tick();
    if ( ++data->counter % 2000 == 0 ) {
      data->scaler += 0.025;
      data->instrument->setFrequency( data->frequency * data->scaler );
    }
  }

  if ( data->counter > 80000 )
    data->done = true;

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  // Set the global sample rate and rawwave path before creating class instances.
  Stk::setSampleRate( 44100.0 );
  Stk::setRawwavePath("./engine/rawwaves/");

  TickData data;
  RtAudio dac;

  // Figure out how many bytes in an StkFloat and setup the RtAudio stream.
  RtAudio::StreamParameters parameters;
  parameters.deviceId = dac.getDefaultOutputDevice();
  parameters.nChannels = 1;
  RtAudioFormat format = ( sizeof(StkFloat) == 8 ) ? RTAUDIO_FLOAT64 : RTAUDIO_FLOAT32;
  unsigned int bufferFrames = RT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  try {
    dac.openStream( &parameters, NULL, format, (unsigned int)Stk::sampleRate(), &bufferFrames, &tick, (void *)&data );
  }
  catch ( RtAudioError& error ) {
    error.printMessage();
    goto cleanup;
  }

  try {
    // Define and load the BeeThree instrument
    data.instrument = new BeeThree();
  }
  catch ( StkError & ) {
    goto cleanup;
  }

  data.frequency = 220.0;
  data.instrument->noteOn( data.frequency, 0.5 );

  try {
    dac.startStream();
  }
  catch ( RtAudioError &error ) {
    error.printMessage();
    goto cleanup;
  }

  // Block waiting until callback signals done.
  std::cin.get();
  data.scaler = 0.025;
  std::cin.get();
  data.scaler = -1;
  std::cin.get();
  
  // Shut down the callback and output stream.
  try {
    dac.closeStream();
  }
  catch ( RtAudioError &error ) {
    error.printMessage();
  }

 cleanup:
  delete data.instrument;

  return 0;
}
```

I managed to compile this simple demo program with g++, using this command:

```
g++ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -D__LINUX_ALSA__ ./engine/engine.cpp -o ./engine/engi -I./engine/include/ -L./engine/lib/ -lstk -lpthread -lasound -lm
```

But then I try to compile it into an `engine.node` file with *node-gyp*, I get this error:

```html
paulux@Paulux-Laptop:~/Documents/Code/FyneWav$ node-gyp build
/usr/bin/ld : can't find -lstk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my `binding.gyp` file:

```py
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "engine",
            "sources": ["./engine/engine.cpp"],
            "cflags_cc" :["-fexceptions"],
            "include_dirs": [
                "./engine/include/"
            ],
            'link_settings': {
                "libraries": [
                    "-lpthread", "-lasound" , "-lm",
                    "-L./engine/lib/", "-lstk"
                ],
            },
            "defines": [
                "__LITTLE_ENDIAN__", "__LINUX_ALSA__"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My folders looks like this:

```html
root
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
|- README.md
|- binding.gyp
|- 10.1.4 (includes for v8 NodeJS addon)
|- engine
   |- engine.cpp
   |- include (all include files from *STK/include* archive)
   |- lib
      |- libstk.a (lib from the *STK/src/Release* archive)
```

I tried not to link `stk` in the `binding.gyp` file, but then I loaded the `engine.node` module in electron, I got:

```
Uncaught Error: /home/paulux/Documents/Code/FyneWav/build/Release/engine.node:
undefined symbol: _ZN3stk3Stk17sampleRateChangedEdd
```

So, the question is:
How can I link `stk` in node-gyp, and, if we can't, how can I make a `engine.node` file using other compilers (like g++ for example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly ! I've found by myself !

The answer is really dumb: in my `binding.gyp` file, I just had to replace

`-L./engine/include` by

`-L/home/paulux/Documents/Code/fynewav/engine/include`.

I just had to change from a relative path to an absolute one...

And it took me a day to figure it out...

And I hate myself =)